# How do I translate hardcoded html placed in footer.php in Wordpress ?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi to all developers !!

I am trying to translate some spans in wordpress.(From Dutch to English)

for example in my footer.php in line 65 I have this span

```
<span class="hd-ft">Navigatie</span>
```

**And I want to translate it to "Navigation"**

I found out that Wordpress translates hardcoded text through **po** and **mo** files.

But what exactly should I add this span element (with the word Navigatie) in po files and how ???

Comment: There are several editors for `.po` files, take your pick. Or do you want to do it with some script?

Comment: Have you read the codex page on translating? http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Comment: @@Wrikken I am usint the "Poedit" but I dont know what how to insert  this code: <span class="hd-ft">Navigatie</span>